# Mouse detection in picture box Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Im currently making a winforms application where I upload a photo into a picture box and I want to use my cursor to hover within the picture box and read the pixel RGB data of where my cursor is on the picture. My first step is to detect when the cursor is in the picture box but I cannot figure out how to add that event in the form designer. Thanks

Comment: You can use MouseMove event. The MouseEventArgs parameter give you information about cursor.

Answer (score 2):

To detect your cursor on picture box, you have to add this function in `EventHandler` class.
This below is an example:

```
PictureBox picture;
picture.MouseHover += new EventHandler(this.PictureBox_MouseHover);
```

`MouseHover` is a variable where you can add more functions.

`PictureBox_MouseHover()` will be your function that you must declare in source code

If you don't find your picturebox in the designer file or in the source code, create your new picturebox variable. Set it how you like. It's more expensive, but you can find that kind of code on the Internet.

***Note:*** In the preview file, where you have graphic of your window form, go in Properties of your picturebox and, in the Events section, you can select the event you need; there will be all events about mouse.